# Sort items so that parents are created before their children

Tags: sorting, powershell

I've been asked to create some code to help automate the loading of data into a system based on employee data in a spreadsheet.  However, the data isn't clean, so some people may have no manager, some may be their own manager, some have managers who already exist in the system, so aren't included in the export, and others managers are somewhere in the export.  Ideally we'd create managers before creating their subordinates, to set both values in one pass (rather than creating all accounts, then updating the managers).

The below sort algorithm is to allow a sort of such dirty data, to ensure that where a dependency chain can be resolved it is and the items are returned in the appropriate order; but if the data's bad, we'll still be able to do as much good as possible.

Sharing it here as there may be a more efficient solution.  I've seem similar solutions which build a tree then traverse it; but all those I've seen require clean data to function correct, and I can't think of a way to amend them whilst keeping their efficiency.

```
Function Sort-ParentChild {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [PSCustomObject[]]$ListItems
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$ParentPropertyName
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$CurrentPropertyName
    )
    Begin {
        [System.Collections.Generic.List[PSCustomObject]]$Pending = [System.Collections.Generic.List[PSCustomObject]]::new()
    }
    Process {
        foreach ($item in $ListItems) {
            # first return items which have no parent, or which are their own parent (since circular dependencies would otherwise never be resolved
            if (($null -eq $item."$ParentPropertyName") -or (($item."$CurrentPropertyName" -eq $item."$ParentPropertyName"))) {
                $item
            } else {
                $Pending.Add($item)
            }
        }
    }
    End {
        while ($Pending.Count) {
            $circularLoop = $true
            # return any items whose parents are not in the pending list (i.e. they already existed so weren't in the todo list, or we've returned them earlier in the process)
            for ($i = ($Pending.Count-1); $i -ge 0; $i--) { # work down, so that removing an item won't have any odd impacts
                if ($Pending[$i]."$ParentPropertyName" -notin @($Pending | Select-Object -ExpandProperty $CurrentPropertyName)) {
                    $Pending[$i]
                    $Pending.RemoveAt($i)
                    $circularLoop = $false # if we've found something to return, we're not in a loop yet
                }
            }
            if ($circularLoop) {
                # in case there are any circular dependencies, to avoid getting stuck, return a single item, then try to unravel in dependency order from there
                Write-Warning "Circular dependency found; breaking loop by returning $($Pending[0]."$CurrentPropertyName")"
                $Pending[0]
                $Pending.RemoveAt(0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Example Usage

```
$users = @(
    @{Id = 'Subordinate17';   ManagerId = 'MiddleManager1'}      
    @{Id = 'Subordinate15';   ManagerId = 'MiddleManager1'}   
    @{Id = 'Subordinate14';   ManagerId = 'MiddleManager3'}   
    @{Id = 'Subordinate13';   ManagerId = 'MiddleManager1'}   
    @{Id = 'TopDog';          ManagerId = $null}      # this person's the top dog; they don't have a manager
    @{Id = 'MiddleManager1';  ManagerId = 'BigBoss1'}
    @{Id = 'BigBoss1';        ManagerId = 'BigBoss1'} # Big Boss is their own boss
    @{Id = 'AmbassadorX';     ManagerId = 'PilotX'}        
    @{Id = 'MiddleManager2';  ManagerId = 'BigBoss1'}
    @{Id = 'PilotX';          ManagerId = 'InstructorX'}   
    @{Id = 'Subordinate17';   ManagerId = 'MiddleManager1'}      
    @{Id = 'MiddleManager3';  ManagerId = 'TopDog'}
    @{Id = 'Subordinate16';   ManagerId = 'MiddleManager3'}      
    @{Id = 'Mya';             ManagerId = 'PilotX'}         
    @{Id = 'Subordinate12';   ManagerId = 'MiddleManager2'}      
    @{Id = 'Subordinate11';   ManagerId = 'MiddleManager1'}      
    @{Id = 'InstructorX';     ManagerId = 'AmbassadorX'}
    @{Id = 'Subordinate10';   ManagerId = 'MiddleManager2'}   
    @{Id = 'Subordinate09';   ManagerId = 'MiddleManager2'}   
    @{Id = 'Subordinate08';   ManagerId = 'MiddleManager2'}   
    @{Id = 'Subordinate07';   ManagerId = 'MiddleManager2'}   
    @{Id = 'Subordinate06';   ManagerId = 'MiddleManager2'}   
    @{Id = 'Subordinate05';   ManagerId = 'TopDog'}   
    @{Id = 'Subordinate04';   ManagerId = 'BigBoss1'}   
    @{Id = 'Subordinate03';   ManagerId = 'MiddleManager3'}   
    @{Id = 'Shark';           ManagerId = $null}           # alone shark :S
    @{Id = 'Subordinate02';   ManagerId = 'MiddleManager3'}   
    @{Id = 'Subordinate01';   ManagerId = 'MiddleManager3'}
) | %{[pscustomobject]$_} #| Sort -Property @{E={[Guid]::NewGuid()}} # optional chaos sort, to avoid any chance of my data being in some helpful order before testing

$users | Sort-ParentChild -ParentPropertyName 'ManagerId' -CurrentPropertyName 'Id'
```

## Example Output

```
WARNING: Circular dependency found; breaking loop by returning AmbassadorX
Id             ManagerId     
--             ---------     
TopDog                       
BigBoss1       BigBoss1      
Shark                        
Subordinate04  BigBoss1      
Subordinate05  TopDog        
MiddleManager3 TopDog        
MiddleManager2 BigBoss1      
MiddleManager1 BigBoss1      
Subordinate13  MiddleManager1
Subordinate14  MiddleManager3
Subordinate15  MiddleManager1
Subordinate17  MiddleManager1
Subordinate01  MiddleManager3
Subordinate02  MiddleManager3
Subordinate03  MiddleManager3
Subordinate06  MiddleManager2
Subordinate07  MiddleManager2
Subordinate08  MiddleManager2
Subordinate09  MiddleManager2
Subordinate10  MiddleManager2
Subordinate11  MiddleManager1
Subordinate12  MiddleManager2
Subordinate16  MiddleManager3
Subordinate17  MiddleManager1
AmbassadorX    PilotX        
InstructorX    AmbassadorX   
PilotX         InstructorX   
Mya            PilotX
```